# Run a SQL subquery based on results of the main query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a better way to do this?

The SQL Server 2008 R2 table-valued function below runs a query to determine how many records there are that match a specific criteria and then performs another query based on the results of the first query.

Is this the right approach? Or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

```
USE [My_MSSQL_Database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetActiveProfileIDForSystemID](@SystemID NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS @retActiveProfileID TABLE 
(
    ActiveUserProfile NVARCHAR(10)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProfileCount NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @ProfilesLookup NVARCHAR(50);

    SELECT @ProfileCount = COUNT(mdl_user.id)
    FROM mdl_user
    INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
    WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 2)
    AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE @SystemID)
    AND mdl_user.id NOT IN (
        SELECT mdl_user.id
        FROM mdl_user
        INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
        WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 4)
        AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE 'Yes')
        AND (mdl_user.deleted = 0)
    )
    AND (mdl_user.deleted = 0);

    IF (@ProfileCount > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ProfilesLookup = mdl_user.id
        FROM mdl_user
        INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
        WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 2)
        AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE @SystemID)
        AND mdl_user.id NOT IN (
            SELECT mdl_user.id
            FROM mdl_user
            INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
            WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 4)
            AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE 'Yes')
            AND (mdl_user.deleted = 0)
        )
        AND (mdl_user.deleted = 0)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ProfilesLookup = mdl_user.id
        FROM mdl_user
        INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
        WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 2)
        AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE @SystemID)
        AND (mdl_user.deleted = 0)
    END

    IF @ProfilesLookup IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT @retActiveProfileID
        SELECT @ProfilesLookup;
    END
    RETURN
END
```

mdl_user_info_data.userid is an implied FK on mdl_user.id
(mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid)

Essentially, what I want to do is:

Run a query that will COUNT how many rows/records there are in the mdl_user_info_data table

```
WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 4)
AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE 'Yes')
```

and
    WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 2)
    AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE @SystemID)

If there are no rows (COUNT = 0) then I want to:

```
SELECT id 
FROM mdl_user_info_data 
WHERE mdl_user_info_data.userid = @SystemID
```

where @SystemID is the @SystemID value passed to the GetActiveProfileIDForSystemID(@SystemID) function when it is called.

The
mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 2 and
mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 4
rows are "user profile" fields in the application (Moodle).

The mdl_user_info_data table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mdl_user_info_data](
 [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [userid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 [fieldid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 [data] [ntext] NOT NULL,
 [dataformat] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [mdl_userinfodata_id_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
```

Comment: There is a certain complexity of a stackoverflow question after which we should be getting paid to answer.

Comment: @MikeNakis, actually, the logic of the function doesn't seem that complex.

Comment: I can't read your answer, my brain hurts, so I am upvoting you for the effort! C-:=

Comment: @MikeNakis, you can see that original code has repeating statements. In essence, the original function deals only with two queries that produce two sets of `ID`s, which I called set `A` and `B` in the answer. I simply showed how it is possible to achieve the same logic without using `IF`, but using `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "better".

From the point of view of ease of understanding and maintenance the current variant could be OK.

From the point of view of performance it most likely can be improved, because you execute the same query twice.

Here is one possible way. This is my understanding of the logic behind this function.

There are two possibly intersecting sets of IDs.

```
A:
SELECT ID
FROM T
WHERE <ExpressionA>

SELECT mdl_user.id
FROM mdl_user
INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 2)
AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE @SystemID)
AND (mdl_user.deleted = 0)


B:
SELECT ID
FROM T
WHERE <ExpressionB>

SELECT mdl_user.id
FROM mdl_user
INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
WHERE (mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 4)
AND (mdl_user_info_data.data LIKE 'Yes')
AND (mdl_user.deleted = 0)
```

> If set `A` minus set `B` has any rows then we return one random row
>   from the difference ELSE return one random row from set `A`.

This is how both sets look like:

```
A: |........................|
B:                  |,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|

   |................|;;;;;;;|,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
         A - B        A x B       B - A
```

> If `A-B` is not empty return `A-B` ELSE return `A` or `AxB` (if `A-B`
>   is empty, then `A = AxB`)

We want to return only one row, not the whole set. So, we can return ordered union of `A-B` plus `AxB` and take the first row of the result.

```
WITH
CTE_A
AS
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM T
    WHERE <ExpressionA>
)
,CTE_B
AS
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM T
    WHERE <ExpressionB>
)
,CTE_OrderedA
AS
(
    -- A - B
    SELECT 1 AS SortOrder, ID
    FROM CTE_A
    WHERE ID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT ID
        FROM CTE_B
    )

    UNION ALL

    -- A x B
    SELECT 2 AS SortOrder, ID
    FROM CTE_A
    WHERE ID IN
    (
        SELECT ID
        FROM CTE_B
    )
)
SELECT TOP(1) ID
FROM CTE_OrderedA
ORDER BY SortOrder
;
```

This query eliminates the need for explicit `IF`. Now you can simplify the function itself and make it an [inline TVF](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx).
It should be more efficient than the current variant, but you should measure actual performance with your real data.

Actually, it could be said that a single query variant is better from the maintenance point of view as well, because the code for the query is not repeated.
But logic behind this could be not obvious.
In any case there should be proper comments explaining the logic.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I'l try that CTE solution. I have edited my origional post and added more information. I'l acceprt the answer once I've tried your CTE solution.

Comment: @luisdev, what did you do eventually? Was my suggestion helpful?

Comment: Vladimir. I am still working on it. I will post the solution here once it is working.